# Is there a way to prevent Angular from generating a blank component.scss file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In angular, when you generate a new component (i.e. `ng generate component`) it creates a new *.scss file to go along with the new component. However, these files are rarely used. Is there a way to suppress creation of this file, and just have it generate the code, spec, and template?

Comment: You could try the `--inline-style` option for the ng generate command. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component).

Comment: What version of the CLI are you working with?

Comment: The latest, 7.1.x I believe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid getting a *scss* file for a component, use the `--inlineStyle=true` (or `-s=true`) option while using the `ng generate component` command (or `ng g c <comp-name> -s=true` for short), as @pzaenger shows in their answer.

If you would like that same behavior to occur by default for a *new* project, you can use the `--inlineStyle=true` (or `-s=true`) option while using the `ng new` command.

If you would like that same behavior to be default for an *existing* project, you will need to add some stuff to your *angular.json* file. See below.

```
...
"projects": {
    "<your project name>": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "prefix": "app",
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "inlineStyle": true,
        "styleext": "scss"
        }
    },
...
```

Add `"inlineStyle": true` in the proper place like shown above.

Then, when you run `ng generate component`, the styles will be inline by default.

**2019-03-20 Update:** updated answer to work with Angular CLI 7.x. The argument names changed since the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`--inline-style`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component), or simply `-s`:

> Specifies if the style will be in the ts file.

Works also for the HTML-markup (`--inline-template`) and so on.

*(Though @R.Richards was faster, I hope my answer is fine)*

Comment: OK, this is a possible way, but is there a way to make this the default behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I guess @R.Richards helps you :)